# Construct defaults dynamically with jinja2 in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In an Ansible role, my current approach for creating a configuration file is creating a dictionary by merging a dictionary in `defaults/main.yml` and user set values with the `combine` filter and let Ansible template that by using the `to_nice_yaml` filter in a jinja2 template.

Now I want to integrate parts into this dictionary in the `defaults/main.yml` that are created dynamically and based on other variables. The goal is to have everything in this dictionary, so it can be templated by ansible in one step using the `to_nice_yaml` filter.

What I tried was something like this:

```yaml
static_dir_by_host: >-
  {% for subdomain in subdomains %}
    '{{ subdomain.name }}.{{ domain_name }}': '{{ static_path }}/static-{{ subdomain.name }}/'
  {% endfor %}
```

Other variations I tried:

```yaml
static_dir_by_host: >-
  {{ '{' }}   
  {% for subdomain in subdomains %}
    '{{ subdomain.name }}.{{ domain}}': '{{ static_path }}/static-{{ subdomain.name }}/'
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  {{ '{' }}
```

```yaml
static_dir_by_host: |
  {{ '{' }}   
  {% for subdomain in subdomains %}
    '{{ subdomain.name }}.{{ domain}}': '{{ static_path }}/static-{{ subdomain.name }}/'
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  {{ '{' }}
```

Nothing worked so far, the results all have faulty line-breaks, extra quotes or braces, for example:
 `static_dir_by_host: '{` from 2nd variation
Is this possible with Ansible, did I maybe miss something obvious?

Comment: Welcome to SO! [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing [Filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#id11). For example, the below defaults

```yaml
shell> cat roles/my_role/defaults/main.yml 
static_dir_by_host: |
  {% filter from_yaml %}
  {% for name in subdomains %}
  {{ name }}.{{ domain_name }}: {{ static_path }}/static-{{ name }}/
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfilter %}
```

and the task

```yaml
shell> cat roles/my_role/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    var: static_dir_by_host
```

in the below playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars:

    subdomains: [h1, h2, h3]
    domain_name: example.org
    static_path: /tmp

  roles:
    - my_role
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  static_dir_by_host:
    h1.example.org: /tmp/static-h1/
    h2.example.org: /tmp/static-h2/
    h3.example.org: /tmp/static-h3/
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
A friend now figured out that I was just missing a comma. what a classic.
So this now workes for me:
  static_dir_by_host: >
    { {% if galaxy_manage_subdomain_static %}
    {% for subdomain in subdomains %}
    '{{ subdomain.name }}.{{ domain_name }}': '{{ static_path }}/static-{{ subdomain.name }}/',
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %} }